# intercalar o maximizar y minimizar 2 ventanas de documento pdf entre ellas cada ciertos segundos

Tags: tkinter

Buen dia, estoy programando algo con lo cual yo ingrese 1 numero en cada Entry y me abra dichos documentos pdf, y que se esten minimizando y maximizando determinado tiempo. soy nuevo en python y hasta ahora me falta el timer para las ventanas de los doc. 
gracias de antemano.

```
#import full module
from tkinter import*
import webbrowser as wb


#windows variable = windows interface
windows = Tk()

windows.title("Visual Help Software")
windows.geometry("400x500")
#windows.configure(background = 'blue')
imagen = PhotoImage(file= "nwico.png")
fondo =  Label(windows, image=imagen, width =300, height = 100).place(x=50, y=130)

#background_image = PhotoImage(file="abl.jpeg")
#image = Image.open('abl.jpg')

etiqueta = Label(windows,text = "Proyeccion de Documentos.")
etiqueta.pack()

def obtener(v_help_e):

  if (v_help_e == "1"):
    wb.open_new(r'C:\Users\dsg02\Desktop\New folder\test\AYUDA VISUAL DE ACOMODO DE HARNES.pdf')

  if (v_help_e == "2"):
    wb.open_new(r'C:\Users\dsg02\Desktop\New folder\test\MSXR BRAKETS UY END PLATE.pdf')


v_help_l = Label(windows, fg="green", text="Proyectar ayuda visual:").place(x=40, y=50)

v_help_e = Entry(windows, width =10,)
v_help_e.bind("<Return>", lambda event: obtener(v_help_e.get()))

v_help_e.place(x=170, y=50)

v_help_e.focus()


boton_e = Button(fg="green", text="Enviar", command=lambda: obtener(v_help_e.get()))
boton_e.place (x=250, y= 45)


def obtenerf(doc_ctq_e): # CTQS

  if (doc_ctq_e == "3"):
    wb.open_new(r'C:\Users\dsg02\Desktop\New folder\test\STD WORD HDP.pdf')

  if (doc_ctq_e == "4"):
    wb.open_new(r'C:\Users\dsg02\Desktop\New folder\test\TZL1D 1 DRIVER.pdf')



doc_ctq_l = Label(windows, fg="green", text="Proyectar CTQS:").place(x=40, y=80)

doc_ctq_e = Entry(windows)
doc_ctq_e.bind("<Return>", lambda event: obtenerf(doc_ctq_e.get()))

doc_ctq_e.place(x=170, y=80)

v_help_e.focus()


boton_e1 = Button(fg="green", text="Enviar", command=lambda: obtenerf(doc_ctq_e.get()))
boton_e1.place (x=310, y= 75)


boton1 = Button(windows, fg="red", text="EXIT", command=windows.quit)
boton1.place(x=250, y=250)

#create event to call windows variable
windows.mainloop()
```